# Why Xubuntu based on Xenial is so slow on my Pentium 4 3GHz?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, xubuntu, gpu-driver

I recently tried to revive an old Pentium 4, and I thought the best would have been to install a light OS. Now, as I know Ubuntu 16 could be too much for such a old computer, I tried installing it along with the Xubuntu desktop (to being able to switch the GUI at run-time).

One thing I noticed is that Ubuntu was indeed super slow, and Xubuntu was a bit better, but still slow. I know there's also Lubuntu out there, but a few questions before I try installing anything else:

1. Would installing Xubuntu as the main OS and not as in parallel with Ubuntu would change something (hope this makes any sense...)?
2. As I have already reached the maximum available RAM (2 GB), I think the video card should be the major blame of such slowness (it says in the additional driver something like "Unknown ... (proprietary)"). Can anybody suggest me a good video card for an old ASUS P5S800-VM motherboard?

Few additional specs on my desktop pc:

- I am currently running the 64bit version of the OS.
- I don't know which video card I have right now (I should check when I'll be back home and update this point).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by installing “in parallel”? Dual-boot, or GUI selection in run-time (e.g. both `ubuntu-desktop` and `xubuntu-desktop` packages installed), or something different?

Comment: Probably RAM is the issue. 2 GB is just enough for a 64-but system. It should run slow.

Comment: The latter. I first installed Ubuntu and then from the terminal did "apt-get install xubuntu-desktop". So it's GUI selection at run-time. This is because I thought I would still get all the packages of Ubuntu with the speed of Xubuntu.

Comment: @Pilot6 Would it be better to install the 32bit version? I also did "sudo apt-get install zram-config" as I read somewhere it can help when having little RAM.

Comment: 32 version should run better. And old Intel CPUs are not good with 64-but anyway.

Comment: @Pilot6 Ok that's a good starting point, thanks!

Comment: @umbe1987 In this case, both desktop environments bring their own applications, possibly making the system slower than any of them individually. And of course, 32-bit version would be better.

Comment: @Melebius Ok, another good hint! Which between Xubuntu and Lubuntu (or others) would have more packages? I mean, Ubuntu has plenty, is it the same for these others?

Comment: Any `?ubuntu-desktop` metapackage provides several applications like office suite, instant messenger etc. and also its own set of system tools like control panels or screensaver. Some of them (like screensaver, at least in my case) may be running same time by default when several desktop environments are installed.

Comment: Ok thanks for the many suggestions. Would you post your comments in form of an answer, I will be happy to accept it!